# pyramid graph in base R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a list of individual age and gender information like this:

```
+-----+--------+
| age | gender |
+-----+--------+
|  46 | male   |
|  33 | female |
|  63 | female |
|  51 | male   |
|  46 | male   |
|  44 | female |
|  27 | male   |
|  38 | female |
|  56 | male   |
+-----+--------+
```

Which i want to visualize in a pyramid graph, like below. I'd like to do this in base R. So far i've tried using packages (like pyramid and ggplot) but pyramid does not have all the options that i need and ggplot is giving me a headache and i need to have a comprehensible code today. What's the best way to approach this?

[image]

This is my code so far. I think i'm halfway there, but i now have two halves of a pyramid graph that i can't seem to combine.

```
age <- as.data.frame(table(age))
age <- dcast(age, age ~ gender)
age <- data.frame(male = paste0("-",as.character(age$male)), female = 
as.character(age$female), ages = as.character(age$age), stringsAsFactors = F)
for (i in 18:80) {
  if(i %!in% age$ages) {
    addrow <- data.frame(male = "0", female = "0", ages = as.character(i), 
stringsAsFactors = F)
    age <- rbind(age, addrow)
  }
}
age <- data.frame(male = as.numeric(age$male), female = 
as.numeric(age$female), ages = as.numeric(age$age), stringsAsFactors = F)
age <- age[order(age$ages),] %>% select(c("male", "female"))

barplot(age$male,
        xlim = c(min(age$male), max(age$female)),
        horiz = T)
barplot(age$female,
        xlim = c(min(age$male), max(age$female)),
        horiz = T)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? where are you stuck? It could be argued that using these packages would be easier than using base R.

Comment: added my code. it's messy, at best. i started R two months ago and i'm still getting used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed we have an age matrix like this:

```
ag
#          5  10 15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75 80
# male   3.2 2.6  5 3.0 2.2 3.8 2.8 3.2 4.2 3.4 3.4 3.2 2.0 2.8 2.2  3
# female 4.6 2.6  4 2.4 1.8 2.8 1.8 3.0 2.8 5.2 3.6 4.2 2.4 2.8 3.0  3
```

Then we may split the rows and draw two `barplot`s separately, one part has to be set to negative.

```
ag.f <- - ag[1, ]
ag.m <- ag[2, ]
```

We need to adjust `xlim` and specify `add=TRUE` in the second plot.

```
mwd <- max(range(ag)) +.5   # for adjustment

## barplots
b <- barplot(ag.f, horiz=T, xlim=c(-mwd, mwd), col=2, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")  # plot left
barplot(ag.m, horiz=T, add=TRUE, col=4, xaxt="n", yaxt="n")  # plot right

## axes
axis(1, at=(-5):5, labels=FALSE, tck=.02)
mtext(paste0(c(5:1, 0:5), "%"), 1, 1, at=(-5):5, las=1)
axis(2, b, labels=FALSE, tck=.02, lty=0)
mtext(colnames(ag), 2, 1, at=b, las=1)

## headers
text(-6, 21, "age", xpd=TRUE, font=2)
text(-2.5, 21, "female", xpd=TRUE, font=2)
text(2.5, 21, "male", xpd=TRUE, font=2)
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Data

```
ag <- structure(c(3.2, 4.6, 2.6, 2.6, 5, 4, 3, 2.4, 2.2, 1.8, 3.8, 
2.8, 2.8, 1.8, 3.2, 3, 4.2, 2.8, 3.4, 5.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.2, 4.2, 
2, 2.4, 2.8, 2.8, 2.2, 3, 3, 3), .Dim = c(2L, 16L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("male", "female"), c("5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", 
    "35", "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70", "75", "80"
    )), .Names = c("", "")))
```